# Custom Jenkins Plugin make Http request from Java

Tags: java, api, jenkins, httprequest, jenkins-plugins

I'm new in Jenkins plugin development and I'm creating a plugin from which I want to make an HTTP request to a REST API and parse JSON result.

I found that I can make fetch() request in Jelly using script tags but I need to do it in Java.

I tried to add some import as:

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
```

when I run `mvn hpi:run` I got the message: 'package java.net.http does not exist'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your version of Java?
If it's java 11, then try like below:

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
```

where the **module name is java.net.http**

Did you add the dependency to the java.net.http package? if not try this:

```
module org.example {
    requires java.httpclient;
    }
```

for more details:
http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/jigsaw/ea/module-summary.html

Comment: You are right it was because I'm using java 8. I changed the library with OkHttpClient and now works fine.

Comment: That's good! can you please mark this as answered and vote my post?